# Matrix Differentiation of Kronecker Product

Tags: matrix-calculus, chain-rule, kronecker-product

I have a question about differentiating an expression which has multiple kronecker products.

I have the following objective function I would like to differentiate with respect to $\mathbf{Q}$:
\begin{equation*}
\lVert\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{Q}\otimes\mathbf{Q}\otimes\mathbf{Q}\otimes\mathbf{Q})\mathbf{x}\rVert^2_2
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times K^4}$, $\mathbf{Q}\in\mathbb{R}^{K\times K}$ and $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{K^4}$. I am confused with how the chain rule works with respect to matrix differentiation. This is how I proceeded:

Let   $ f=\lVert\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{Q}\otimes\mathbf{Q}\otimes\mathbf{Q}\otimes\mathbf{Q})\mathbf{x}\rVert^2_2$
and $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{Q}\otimes\mathbf{Q}\otimes\mathbf{Q}\otimes\mathbf{Q}$. Therefore $\frac{df}{d\mathbf{Q}}=\frac{df}{d\mathbf{B}}\frac{d\mathbf{B}}{d\mathbf{Q}}$

When I calculate $\frac{df}{d\mathbf{B}}=\mathbf{A}^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{ABx})\mathbf{x}^T$ I gain a $\mathbb{R}^{K^4\times K^4}$ matrix not a $\mathbb{R}^{K\times K}$ matrix that I am hoping for. 
Therefore I am using the chain rule wrong because of the change in dimensions i.e scalar to matrix.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Of course $df/dB$ is $K^4\times K^4$. $B$ itself is $K^4\times K^4$. There is no mystery here

Comment: Thanks for your comments! In reply to your first comment I agree there is no mystery but I was lead to believe a scalar-matrix differential has the same dimensions as the matrix i.e $dim(\frac{df}{d\mathbf{Q}})=dim(\mathbf{Q})$ therefore it seems like the chain rule in this case does not preserve dimensionality. Secondly thanks for your longer answer, that definitely clears up part of my question :)

Comment: Yes, $\frac{df}{dQ}$ has the same dimension as $Q$, that is correct. The problem is how you interpret $\frac{df}{dB}\frac{dB}{dQ}$. The former is a $k^4\times k^4$ matrix, the second a $(k^4\times k^4)\times(k\times k)$ tensor, and you have to contract the correct indices to obtain the chain rule:
$$
\frac{df}{dQ_{ij}} = \sum_{k,l=1}^{k^4} \frac{df}{dB_{kl}} \frac{dB_{kl}}{dQ_{ij}}
= \sum_{k,l=1}^{k^4} \left(\frac{df}{dB}\right)_{kl} \frac{dB_{kl}}{dQ_{ij}}
$$

Comment: Thanks Federico, you have cleared things up there. I appreciate your help.

Comment: So the contraction between $\frac{df}{dB}$ and $\frac{dB}{dQ}$ is what some people call double dot product. But my advice is to write out the indices in order to not commit mistakes

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: Addendum: see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348739/double-dot-product-vs-double-inner-product), where the OP is deeply depressed by the confusion with different definitions of the "double inner/dot product" $A:B$. My personal advice is to avoid those confusing notations and write everything explicitly, unless it's **extremely clear** what the conventions are. In particular, the notation $\frac{dF}{dB}\frac{dB}{dQ}$ is not confusing to me, because there is only one obvious way to contract it in order to make it do the correct thing

Comment: Hi Federico, to clarify does $\frac{dB_{kl}}{dQ_{ij}}=\Big(\frac{dB}{dQ_{ij}}\Big)_{kl}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: the derivative of $Q\otimes Q\otimes Q\otimes Q$ with respect to $Q$ is a mess, at first sight...

Let's start simple. Let $Q$ be a $K\times K$ matrix with entries $Q_{ij}$ and let $E^{ab}$ be the $K\times K$ matrix with all $0$ entries, except the entry $(a,b)$ which is $1$; in other words, $(E^{ab})_{ij} = \delta_a^i\delta_b^j$.

Then I claim that
$$
\frac{\partial(Q\otimes Q)}{\partial Q_{ij}} = E^{ij}\otimes Q+Q\otimes E^{ij} .
$$
I leave it to you to see why, because trying to write out the involved matrices will probably crash the entire Stack Exchange network...

Jokes aside, this is really immediate to see: just write $Q\times Q$ as in the first formula of the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Definition) and think which elements are affected by $Q_{ij}$. There is the entire $(i,j)$th block, so you get $E^{ij}\otimes Q$, but there is also the $(i,j)$th entry in each block, which gives you $Q\otimes E^{ij}$.

Now, if $A$ and $B$ are matrices which are functions of $Q$, by the same reasoning you get
$$
\frac{\partial(A\otimes B)}{\partial Q_{ij}} = \frac{\partial A}{\partial Q_{ij}}\otimes B + A\otimes \frac{\partial B}{\partial Q_{ij}} .
$$

So you can iterate for instance
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial (Q\otimes Q\otimes Q)}{\partial Q_{ij}}
&= \frac{\partial(Q\otimes Q)}{\partial Q_{ij}}\otimes Q
+ (Q\otimes Q)\otimes \frac{\partial Q}{\partial Q_{ij}} \\
&= (E^{ij}\otimes Q+Q\otimes E^{ij})\otimes Q + (Q\otimes Q)\otimes E^{ij} \\
&= E^{ij}\otimes Q\otimes Q + Q\otimes E^{ij}\otimes Q + Q\otimes Q\otimes E^{ij}.
\end{split}
$$

Now you can prove by induction that
$$
\frac{\partial \bigl(\bigotimes_{n=1}^N Q\bigr)}{\partial Q_{ij}}
= \sum_{n=1}^N \left(\bigotimes_{h=1}^{n-1} Q\right) \otimes E^{ij} \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{h=n+1}^{N} Q\right).
$$

Written more concisely,
$$
\frac{\partial Q^{\otimes N}}{\partial Q_{ij}}
= \sum_{n=1}^N Q^{\otimes (n-1)}\otimes E^{ij} \otimes Q^{\otimes (N-n)} .
$$

Comment: Hi Federico, would you know how to write this in tensor or matrix form instead of index form?

Comment: @shex95 I'm not sure there is a nicer more compact way of writing it, but I may be wrong.