# Khatri Rao product with itself

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, kronecker-product

Consider $U \in R^{n*r} $, is there a way I can represent Khatri Rao product of $U$ with itself repeated $M$ times in any form of $U$?

$$(U \odot U \odot ....\odot U) = f(U)$$
where $(U \odot U)$ represents the Khatri Rao product. What would be this $f(U) \in R^{n*r} \to R^{n^M*r} $ ?

Answer (score 1):

If the columns of the matrix are given by
$$U = \left[\matrix{u_1&u_2\ldots&u_n}\right]$$
Then the columns of the iterated Khatri-Rao product are given
$$U^{\odot M}
= \left[\matrix{u_1^{\otimes M}&u_2^{\otimes M}\ldots&u_n^{\otimes M}}\right]$$
where the iterated Kronecker product of a vector with itself has been denoted by 
$$a^{\otimes M}
= \operatorname*{\bigotimes}\limits_{k=1}^M a
\;=\; a\otimes a\otimes\ldots\otimes a
$$
If you like you can use the standard basis vectors $\{e_k\}$ to rearrange things.
$$\eqalign{
u_k &= Ue_k \\
u_k^{\otimes M} &= U^{\otimes M}\,e_k^{\otimes M} \\
U^{\odot M} &= U^{\otimes M}
\left[\matrix{e_1^{\otimes M}&e_2^{\otimes M}\ldots&e_n^{\otimes M}}\right] \\
&= U^{\otimes M}\,E_M \\
}$$
This reformulation swaps the iterated Khatri product for an iterated Kronecker product, multiplied by a very large *sparse* binary matrix.

Comment: Thanks for this. One more doubt, I didn't mention this here still, would you be able to guess what would be the differentiation of $U^{\otimes M}\,E_M$ wrt $U$ ?

Comment: Here's a [wonderful explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038058/matrix-differentiation-of-kronecker-product/3038272#3038272) on how to calculate such things.