# Properties of the indices of the Kronecker product

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices, kronecker-product

I am working with function (and their derivatives) of matrices, in particular of symmetric and positive definite (SPD) matrices. I am interested in keeping a matrix notation as long as possible, instead of using vectorization.

The specific problem that I am facing now is with the Kronecker product and how to manage the object that it produces. Specifically, I obtained (some context will be provided below) this product (note the explicit indexes):
$$ A_{ik}A_{jl} - B_{ik}A_{jl} - B_{il}A_{jk} $$
where $A$ and $B$ are squared, with the same dimension $p$ and SPD matrices. My question is: can I rewrite this object as a Kronecker product? If yes, it exists some way to clean up the two second terms? At the first question, I would be tempted to write something along
$$ (A \otimes A + B \otimes A)_{p(i-1)+j, p(k-1)+l} - (B \otimes A)_{p(i-1)+j, p(l-1)+k}$$
(I am following the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) here).
Is it possible to obtain a cleaner expression?

**Context:**

What I am trying to do is to obtain the Hessian of the Loglikelihood for a Multivariate Normal distribution. This in practice requires to compute the derivatives of:
$$ l = -\frac{n}{2}\log\det\left|\Sigma\right| - \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}\left[S\Sigma^{-1}\right] $$
with $S=XX^\top$ a symmetric matrix obtained from the data (in this setting I am considering the mean equal to $0$) and $\Sigma$ the covariance matrix.

I have to compute $\partial l/\partial\Sigma$ and then $\partial^2l/(\partial\Sigma\partial\Sigma)$. If I have not made mistakes, they are:
$$ \frac{\partial l}{\partial\Sigma} = -\frac{n}{2}\Sigma^{-1} + \frac{1}{2}\Sigma^{-1}S\Sigma^{-1}$$ 
and 
$$ \frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial\Sigma_{ij}\partial\Sigma_{kl}} = \Sigma^{-1}_{ik}\Sigma^{-1}_{jl} - (\Sigma^{-1}S\Sigma^{-1})_{ik}\Sigma^{-1}_{jl} - (\Sigma^{-1}S\Sigma^{-1})_{il}\Sigma^{-1}_{jk}$$ which is the expression that I wrote at the beginning of the question (with $A=\Sigma^{-1}$ and $B=\Sigma^{-1}S\Sigma^{-1}$).

Thus, if you notice some error here that could save my day! :D

**Disclaimer**

I know that what I am trying to do can be obtained more easily by using the vec and vech operators to work with standard vectors, but I would really prefer to keep the matrix notation for as long as possible. If that was not possible, I will be forced to transform the matrices (and I mostly know how to do it, but in any case that would be another question), but I hope to avoid it.

Thank y'all for the help!

Comment: Thank you, of course I would randomly miss it! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ease of typing, define 
$$\eqalign{
M &= \Sigma^{-1} \;\implies\; dM = -M\,d\Sigma\,M
}$$
Your gradient is correct, so let's start with that and find its differential.
$$\eqalign{
G &= -\tfrac{1}{2} (nM-MSM) \\
dG
 &= -\tfrac{1}{2} (n\,dM-dM\,SM-MS\,dM) \\
 &= +\tfrac{1}{2} (n\,M\,d\Sigma\,M-M\,d\Sigma\,M\,SM-MSM\,d\Sigma\,M) \\
 &= +\tfrac{1}{2} (n\,M\,d\Sigma\,M-M\,d\Sigma\,(2G+nM)-(2G+nM)\,d\Sigma\,M) \\
 &= -\tfrac{1}{2} (n\,M\,d\Sigma\,M+2M\,d\Sigma\,G+2G\,d\Sigma\,M) \\
}$$
At this point, we'd normally use vec/vech operations, but you don't want to do that. 

So let's introduce the double-dot product between tensors
$$\eqalign{
A={\cal B}:C \;\implies\; A_{ij}= \sum_{k,l} {\cal B}_{ijkl}C_{kl} \\
}$$
Let's also introduce the 4th order isotropic tensor ${\cal E}$ with components 
${\cal E}_{ijkl} = \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}$

This tensor is the identity for the double-dot product, i.e. 
$\;A:{\cal E}= A = {\cal E}:A$

Another useful property is untangling matrix products 
$\implies A\,dX\,B = A{\cal E}B^T:dX$

Continuing from before 
$$\eqalign{
dG &= -\tfrac{1}{2} \big(n\,M{\cal E}M+2M{\cal E}G+2G{\cal E}M\big):d\Sigma \\
{\cal H} = \frac{\partial G}{\partial \Sigma}
 &= -\tfrac{1}{2} \big(n\,M{\cal E}M+2M{\cal E}G+2G{\cal E}M\big) \\
{\cal H}_{ijkl} = \frac{\partial G_{ij}}{\partial \Sigma_{kl}}
 &= -\tfrac{1}{2} \big(n\,M_{ip}{\cal E}_{pjkq}M_{ql}
 + 2M_{ip}{\cal E}_{pjkq}G_{ql}
 + 2G_{ip}{\cal E}_{pjkq}M_{ql}\big) \\
 &= -\tfrac{n}{2}M_{ik}M_{jl} -M_{ik}G_{jl} -G_{ik}M_{jl} \\
}$$
I think it looks better with the $G$'s but you can eliminate them in favor of $S,M,\pm$ signs, and more indices.
$$\eqalign{
{\cal H}_{ijkl}
 &= \tfrac{1}{2} \big(
n\,M_{ik}M_{jl}
 - M_{ik}M_{jp}S_{pq}M_{ql}
 - M_{ip}S_{pq}M_{qk}M_{jl}\big) 
\\
 &= \tfrac{1}{2} \big(
n\,M_{ik}M_{jl}
 - M_{ik}(MSM)_{jl}
 - (MSM)_{ik}M_{jl}\big) 
\\
}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can you suggest a reference for some introduction to tensor algebra? Because I found at least two different definitions of the double-dot product and neither is similar to yours! :(
I found one answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348739/double-dot-product-vs-double-inner-product) that gives some sort of insight, but also there they didn't provide references.

Comment: Almost any textbook on _Continuum Mechanics_ will cover tensor algebra and tensor calculus. I believe Dover publications has a couple of good ones in their catalog.